# Given a constraint function to a subject function . Extremize the subject function, finding the maxima and minima using Lagrange multiplier

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

Question :

Let $$ f(x,y)=x^3y,~~~~~g(x,y)= x^2+2xy+5y^2-10 $$

then seek to maximize and minimize $f$ subject to the constraint $g=0$ by the method of Lagrange multipliers.

My attempt :

Partial-differentiation :

$$\nabla f(x,y) = (3x^2y )~\hat{i} + (x^3) ~\hat{j} $$

$$\nabla g(x,y) = (2x+2y) ~\hat{i}+(2x+10y) ~\hat{j} $$

Using Lagrange multipliers method :

$$ \nabla f(x,y) = \lambda\, \nabla g(x,y)$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} ~3x^2y\\ x^3\end{pmatrix}= \lambda \begin{pmatrix} ~2x+2y\\ 2x+10y\end{pmatrix}$$

$$ \tag{1}3x^2y = \lambda\,(2x+2y) $$

$$\tag{2} x^3 = \lambda \,(2x+10y)$$

Making y the subject from equation (1) :

$$ 3x^2y-2 \lambda y= 2 \lambda x$$
$$ \tag{3} y = \frac{2 \lambda x }{3x^2-2 \lambda} $$

Replacing y in equation (2) :

$$ x^3-2 \lambda x = 10 \lambda \left(\frac{2 \lambda x }{3x^2 - 2 \lambda} \right)$$

Rearranging to solve for $\lambda$ :

$$(x^2- 2 \lambda) ~(3x^2-2 \lambda) = 20 \lambda^2$$

$$ 16 \lambda^2 +8x^2 \lambda -3x^4 = 0$$

Solving the quadratic equation for $\lambda$ :

$$ \lambda =\frac{-8x^2\pm \sqrt{(8x^2)^2 - 4(16)(-3x^4)}}{2(16)}$$

$$ \lambda = \frac{-8x^2\pm \sqrt{256x^4}}{2(16)} $$

$$  \lambda = \frac{x^2}{4}, ~-\frac{3x^2}{4}$$

Replacing $\lambda$ in (3) :

For $ \lambda = \frac{x^2}{4}$ :

$$ y = \frac{x}{5} $$

For $\lambda = -\frac{3x^2}{4}$ :

$$ y = -\frac{x}{3}$$

**One of the options of the Q which nearly matches my solution states :
The maximum and minimum are attained at points on the lines $y = x/3$ and $y = -x/5$**

**But :
The solution I got is $ y = -x/3 $ and $y = x/5$**

I am not sure what went wrong and wheather my steps are correct or not. Could you guys please help me out.

**Edit :**

Other options to the question :

1.) The maximum is $125/16$; the minimum is $-675/16$

2.) The maximum is $675/16$; the minimum is $-675/16$

3.) the equation $g = 0 $  gives a hyperbola, so there is no maximum for $f$.

4.) at the maximum and minimum $(x,y)$, the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ satisfies

$$\begin{pmatrix} ~3x^2\\ x^3\end{pmatrix}= \lambda \begin{pmatrix} ~2x+2y\\ 2x+10y\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: When you divided by $3x^2 -2\lambda$ in (3) you may have lost solutions because it is possible to have $3x^2 = 2\lambda$. Check that case!

Comment: I did *not* check your computations, but my computations led to the same conclusion as yours.

Comment: @JohnD thanks for the response I will go through it

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks for your response and attempt, I’m not sure wheather the solutions in the option are incorrect.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I  have added other options. Do you think any of those might be correct?

Comment: The first option is correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Could you please suggest how ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos    I just want to clarify are you saying this is the correct option The maximum is $125/16$; the minimum is $-675/16$ ?

Comment: Yes. See my answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos appreciate a lot I will go through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the method of Lagrange multipliers, you get the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}3x^2y=2\lambda x+2\lambda y\\x^3=2\lambda x+10\lambda y\\x^2+2xy+5y^2=10.\end{array}\right.\tag1$$So, we have$$15x^2y-x^3=5(2\lambda x+2\lambda y)-(2\lambda x+10\lambda y)=8\lambda x.\tag2$$Is there a solution of the system $(1)$ with $x=0$? Yes; it's easy to see that there are actually two of them: $\left(0,\pm\sqrt2\right)$.

If $x\ne0$, then it follows from $(2)$ that $15xy-x^2=8\lambda$, or $\lambda=\frac18x(15y-x)$. This leads to the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x^3=\frac14(x+5y)x(15y-x)\\x^2+2xy+5y^2=10.\end{array}\right.\tag3$$Since we are assuming that $x\ne0$, the first equation of $(3)$ can be simplified into $x^2-2xy-15y^2=0$. It is now easy to see that the solutions of $(3)$ are $\pm\left(\frac52,\frac12\right)$ and $\pm\left(\frac{3\sqrt5}2,-\frac{\sqrt5}2\right)$. Now, computing the value of $f$ at the six solutions of $(1)$ that were found above, we get that the maximum is $\frac{125}{16}$ (attained at $\pm\left(\frac52,\frac12\right)$) and that the minimum is $-\frac{675}{16}$ (attained at $\pm\left(\frac{3\sqrt5}2,-\frac{\sqrt5}2\right)$). So, the first option is correct.

Comment: I’m nearly done going through the solution just a slight doubt shouldn’t it be $+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$ instead of negative ?. As I realize $x= -3y $ is replaced in the constraint function.

Comment: No. You have $x^2-2xy-15y^2=0\iff x=-3y$ or $x=5y$. The solutions of $x^2+2xy+5y^2=10$ with $x=-3y$ are $y=\pm\frac{\sqrt5}2$ and then $x=\mp3\frac{\sqrt5}2$. And the solutions of $x^2+2xy+5y^2=10$ with $x=5y$ are $y=\pm\frac12$ and then $x=\pm\frac52$.

Comment: Oh okay, makes sense. Sign flips

Comment: So, out of all 8 possible solutions $(3\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}, \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2})$ and $ (-3\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}, -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2})$ are removed and 6 are left. Right?

Comment: Which $8$ solutions? I only found $6$ of them.

Comment: My mistake, 6 solutions you are right. Thanks a lot. Understood all steps.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.